# Textfield Values missing while searching

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, material-table

My textfield values go missing when I search for keywords that match that particular field. Posting full code of my materialtable library used.

```
<MaterialTable
    columns={[
        { title: 'Customer Name', field: 'custName', editable: 'never' },
        { title: 'Order Amount', field: 'orderAmount', render: rowData => 
            <TextField
                size="small"
                required
                onChange={e => {
                    this.props.getUpdatedOrderAmount(e.target.value, rowData)}
                }
                value={this.state.value}
            />
        }
    ]}
    data={data}
/>
```

Comment: How are you using columns. Please post complete code.

Comment: @Sandy have posted full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searching use cell's property customFilterAndSearch like:

```
{ title: 'Full name', searchable: true, 
  customFilterAndSearch: (filter: any, rowData: any, columnDef: any): boolean => {
    const s = (rowData.firstName + ' ' + rowData.lastName).toLocaleLowerCase();
    return s.indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
  },
  render: rowData => rowData.firstName + ' ' + rowData.lastName
},
```